# How to install jars related to spark-redis in databricks cluster?

Tags: python, pyspark, redis, azure-redis-cache, spark-redis

I am trying to connect to Azure cache for redis from databricks .

I have installed this package **com.redislabs:spark-redis:2.3.0** from maven package in databricks. I have created a spark session with below code

```
SparkSession\
.builder\
.appName("myApp")\ 
.config("spark.redis.host", "my host")\ 
.config("spark.redis.port", "6379")\
.config("spark.redis.auth", "passwd")\ 
.getOrCreate()
```

But when I ran `df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis").option("table", "people").option("key.column", "name").save()`

I am getting below error.

```
*Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o390.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.redis. Please find packages at
http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html*
```

Could you please let me know the detailed steps to install all necessary libraries/jars to access redis in databricks.

I have seen below code in [spark-redis python doc](https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/blob/master/doc/python.md) but I don't know how to run it in databricks.

```
$ ./bin/pyspark --jars <path-to>/spark-redis-<version>-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

And also please let me know what is the latest spark-redis version.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but you can have a look at `init scripts`. Databricks natively supports external JAR files using them.

Comment: From the exception, it looks like the spark-redis jar is not found among cluster dependencies. How did you install the spark-redis? Do you use an interactive cluster or job?

Answer (score -1):

> Redis has a [Spark Package](http://spark-packages.org/package/RedisLabs/spark-redis) that you can download and attach to your cluster

The following [notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/redis.html) shows how to use Redis with Apache Spark in Azure Databricks.

For more details, refer to [Azure Databricks - Redis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/redis).

Comment: This link and notebook are in scala. But I would need python as mentioned in the question . Could you please let me know how to install the above mentioned jar with version.

Comment: -1: copy-pasted answer from here, with same caveats: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/766408/how-to-install-jars-libraries-related-to-spark-red.html

Comment: @123 It's same answer provided by me on MS Q&A platform. If the person is same how would you say it is copy-pasted from here :( :( :(